# DoCmdApplyFilter does not recognise text input field

Tags: vba, ms-access, filtering

I have a form in ms access I want to filter between two dates updated on the click of a button. The field I want to filter is called Date

The dates to be filtered by are entered though a couple of a textboxs in short date format called TxtDtStrt and TxtDtEnd
the button is called NCRDateFilter

Using the NCRDateFilter button event procedure 'On Click' and the below code I would expect the form the be filtered by date range between TxtDtStrt and TxtDtEnd values

```vb
Private Sub NCRDateFilter_Click()

    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Date] Between [TxtDtStrt] And [TxtDtEnd]", ""

End Sub
```

But it doesn't use the TxtDtStrt/TxtDtEnd values, instead shows popups asking for the TxtDtStrt and then another for the TxtDtEnd value....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with static values (see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/office/vba/api/access.docmd.applyfilter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dda-DK%26k%3Dk(vbaac10.chm4142)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) example):

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, worked a treat.
So pretty much the bit i was missing was I needed to specify the format as well